# How to configure the logo in metadata contacts

Tags: metadata, geonetwork

I can't see the logo in the contact information of my metadata.

[image]

```
<cit:logo>
   <mcc:MD_BrowseGraphic>
      <mcc:fileName>
         <gco:CharacterString>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png</gco:CharacterString>
      </mcc:fileName>
      <mcc:fileDescription>
         <gco:CharacterString>Logo</gco:CharacterString>
      </mcc:fileDescription>
      <mcc:fileType>
         <gco:CharacterString>PNG</gco:CharacterString>
      </mcc:fileType>
      <mcc:linkage>
         <cit:CI_OnlineResource>
            <cit:linkage>
               <gco:CharacterString>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png</gco:CharacterString>
            </cit:linkage>
            <cit:protocol>
               <gco:CharacterString>WWW:LINK-1.0-http--link</gco:CharacterString>
            </cit:protocol>
            <cit:name gco:nilReason="missing">
               <gco:CharacterString/>
            </cit:name>
            <cit:description gco:nilReason="missing">
               <gco:CharacterString/>
            </cit:description>
            <cit:function>
               <cit:CI_OnLineFunctionCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/resources/Codelists/cat/codelists.xml#CI_OnLineFunctionCode"
                                          codeListValue="fileAccess"/>
            </cit:function>
            <cit:protocolRequest gco:nilReason="missing">
               <gco:CharacterString/>
            </cit:protocolRequest>
         </cit:CI_OnlineResource>
      </mcc:linkage>
   </mcc:MD_BrowseGraphic>
</cit:logo>
```

I'm using version 4.2.2 of geonetwork and the iso 19115 standard.

How to configure the logo in metadata contacts ?
Is any additional configuration required?

Thank you for your help